# A website to visualize page links hierarchy in a website

Tags: html, web, hyperlink

Is there an application or a website (pref. website) that enable you to create a link hierarchy of your website?

I need to visualize it to present it to the client.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Why do you not print [tree view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28Unix%29) of website folder ?

Answer (score 0):

You could build the graphic using Microsoft Office, Open Office, or Google Docs.

Microsoft Office => **Visio** http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/
Open Office => **Draw** http://www.openoffice.org/product/draw.html 
Google Docs => **Drawing** https://drive.googleblog.com/2010/04/introducing-google-docs-drawings.html

Answer (score 0):

I just found this tool which, though I only started and havent fully used it, I am actually using it for the first time right now and it looks to be pretty good for what it is.

It will crawl your site gathering quite a bit of information which you can then export directly into GraphViz or any other datavisualization tool.

[Xenu (freeware)](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html)

Additionally, to backup Banath's answer.. If you want to go the route of a wire-frame/flowchart program, I use Omnigraffle and recommend it highly.